# How to create temporary directory structure with files

Tags: java, junit

I faced the following issue: I want to create simple directory structure consisting of one root folder, two childFolders and each child folder should contain two files. How I did it and what doesn't work:

```
TemporaryFolder temp = new TemporaryFolder();
File rootFolder = temp.newFolder("rootFolder");
File child1 = temp.newFolder(rootFolder.getName(), "childFolder1");
File child2 = temp.newFolder(rootFolder.getName(), "childFolder2");
```

Above code creates directory structure properly. I can't create files under given folders because newFile() method takes filename only (which cannot contain special chars) and creates files under root temp not in the tree I created. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I think using more of what the File class has to offer will help.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

I think you would have a more typical approach if you tried something like this:

```
File tempfldr = new File("C:\\rootFolder\\childFolder1");
tempfldr.mkdirs();
File tempfldr2 = new File("C:\\rootFolder\\childFolder2");
tempfldr2.mkdirs();
File child1 = File.createTempFile("prefix_val", "suffix_val", tempfldr);
File child2 = File.createTempFile("prefix_val", "suffix_val", tempfldr2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `java.io.File`:

```
new File(child1, "some-file.txt")
```

will create a file named "some-file.txt" under the `child1` folder. They will still be cleaned up as temporary files by the `TemporaryFolder` Rule. You are using the `@Rule` annotation, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was struggling to use sth from JUnit. You are right as I use @Rule annotation the files created with File api will be removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nothin specific to junit for creating temp file?link to the API for java.io.File createTempFile static method that takes in a directory and prefix suffix http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)

Comment: Please edit your answer to add context from the link. It helps to avoid problems caused by link rot..